# Angular Material | Metadata version mismatch for module

Tags: angular, angular-material, metadata

We've been pulling our hair out trying to solve a `Metadata version mismatch for module` error for Angular Material, which is preventing us from completing the final build on this application. For reference, we're using Angular4. We get this error when trying to run `ng serve` in order to run the app locally. The interesting thing is that once we run `ng serve` and the build fails due to the below error, if we just go into any file and add a new blank line anywhere in the file and save (which automatically re-runs `ng serve`), then the app will compile successfully (as seen at the bottom of the console output `webpack: Compiled successfully.` -- that is where we added a new blank line and re-saved):

```
UserNameHere influx-archiver2 (master) > ng serve

@angular/compiler-cli@4.3.0 requires typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0' but 2.5.2 was found instead.
Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.

Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.

npm install typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0'

To disable this warning run "ng set warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".

** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-05-11T17:33:43.081Z
Hash: d5a1d43de98307f01054
Time: 20633ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 758 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 575 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 735 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 19.5 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol MatModule in /Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/src/app/shared/mat.module.ts, resolving symbol MatModule in /Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/src/app/shared/mat.module.ts
 at Error (native)
 at syntaxError (/Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1725:34)
 at simplifyInContext (/Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24950:23)
 at StaticReflector.simplify (/Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24962:13)
 at StaticReflector.annotations (/Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24392:41)
 at _getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
 at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (/Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
 at /Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:129:27
 at Array.reduce (native)
 at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (/Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:128:10)
 at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (/Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
 at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:91:39)
 at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:240:66)
 at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (/Users/UserNameHere/Desktop/InfluxArchiver2/influx-archiver2/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:493:24)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

webpack: Failed to compile.
webpack: Compiling...
Date: 2018-05-11T17:33:54.396Z - Hash: d473e8f60486dc05c5c4 - Time: 5079ms
5 unchanged chunks

webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Here's our package.json:

```
{
  "name": "influx-archiver2",
  "version": "0.0.16-SNAPSHOT",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "jenkins-build": "echo \"placeholder for your jenkins-build script\""
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^10.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "hover.css": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng-spin-kit": "^5.1.1",
    "ng2-filter-pipe": "^0.1.10",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "1.9.1",
    "ngx-dropdown": "0.0.22",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "tinymce": "^4.6.6",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "@types/node": "8.0.26",
    "codelyzer": "3.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "spar": {
    "name": "influx-archiver2",
    "rootPath": "./dist"
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! We're stumped on how to specifically solve this error, and why adding a new blank line allows the app to compile

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended fixing this by upgrading to Angular5 (as this particular RC of Material was only compatible with Angular5.)

Run:

`npm install @angular/animations@^5.0.0 @angular/common@^5.0.0 @angular/compiler@^5.0.0 @angular/compiler-cli@^5.0.0 @angular/core@^5.0.0 @angular/forms@^5.0.0 @angular/http@^5.0.0 @angular/platform-browser@^5.0.0 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^5.0.0 @angular/platform-server@^5.0.0 @angular/router@^5.0.0 typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@^5.5.2`

and

`npm install typescript@2.4.2 --save-exact`

Then update package.json to utilize the following working dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

That fixed this particular error!

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted so that others know that this question has already been answered.